# Why does Stripe checkout Webhooks send customer_email to null?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I try to get the customer email after a payment on Checkout Stripe new interface. The JSON posted by stripe Webhook always send customer_email with null value.

The stripe Checkout page ask for customer email so I don't understand why Stripe send back this value to null.

Though, customer value is not null.

```
{
  "id": "evt_1FItv8Kj5elW7ZcvEuY6",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2019-03-14",
  "created": 1568539286,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_123123123",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "https://www.example.fr/canceled",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "customer": "cus_FoWzBx2yusHfs9",
      "customer_email": null,
      "display_items": [
        {
          "amount": 1000,
          "currency": "eur",
          "quantity": 1,
          "sku": {
            "id": "sku_1234567",
            "object": "sku",
            "active": true,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "Product test"
            },
            "created": 1568538814,
            "currency": "eur",
            "image": null,
            "inventory": {
              "quantity": null,
              "type": "infinite",
              "value": null
            },
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "package_dimensions": null,
            "price": 1000,
            "product": "prod_FoWr00dX3",
            "updated": 1568538814
          },
          "type": "sku"
        }
      ],
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "mode": "payment",
      "payment_intent": "pi_1FItj5elW70Z2",
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "setup_intent": null,
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": null,
      "success_url": "https://www.example.fr/success"
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The email the customer entered is actually on the Customer object that the CheckoutSession links to. [0] The `customer_email` field is something else(it's the field that your code might have set to prefill an email into the Session).

So retrieve the Customer object from the API (`cus_FoWzBx2yusHfs9`) and check the `email` field there; or retrieve the Session object and [expand the Customer field.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810851/why-doesnt-stripe-checkout-add-customer-name-to-customer-record/57810981#57810981)

[0] - https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-email