# Stripe API, How can I get"customer_email" when Checkout Session executed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I want Django App to send a confirmation email to a customer when webhook is executed,

In order to send an email, I need to get the customer's email address when they make payment.

But the JSON posted by stripe Webhook always sends customer_email with null value.

Here's the result from the part of Webhook object.

```
{
  "api_version": "2020-08-27",
  "created": 1623048315,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "allow_promotion_codes": null,
      "amount_subtotal": 1,
      "amount_total": 1,
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "http://3.129.28.xxx/subscriptions/cancel/",
      "client_reference_id": "1",
      "currency": "jpy",
      "customer": "cus_Jcrw9AXrxWB91I",
      "customer_details": {
        "email": null,
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": []
      },
      "customer_email": null,
      "id": "cs_test_a1gup9kG1ArIxORROMUbKqg6eBnIknoYdgQARcr3AS14DGo2gLFfVnxxxx",
```

You can see **"customer_email": null,**

And **"customer_details"**'s **"email"** is also null,

Therefore I thought I need to get "customer_email" when "create_checkout_session" is executed.

So I added **"customer_email=userEmail"** in create_checkout_session

**view.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # domain_url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
        domain_url = 'http://3.129.28.206/'
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                customer_email=userEmail,
                client_reference_id=request.user.id if request.user.is_authenticated else None,
                success_url=domain_url + 'subscriptions/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url=domain_url + 'subscriptions/cancel/',
                payment_method_types=['card'],
                mode='subscription',
                line_items=[
                    {
                        'price': settings.STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
                        'quantity': 1,
                    }
                ]
            )
            return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

But it does not work. So I tried a different attempt.

**customer_email = request.org.billing_email**

It also does not work. and there is no error message about it, just unable to move to Stripe payment page when I write a code like this.

What should I add after **"customer_email ="** to get the customer's email?

Is there any template variable like **{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}**?

I read this post but could not adopt my case.
[Why does Stripe checkout Webhooks send customer_email to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943676/why-does-stripe-checkout-webhooks-send-customer-email-to-null)

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: what does " but could not adopt my case" mean? The answer you linked is the answer — you would retrieve the Customer object when handling the webhook. I.e. write code to call https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve with the ID of the customer (cus_Jcrw9AXrxWB91I) read from the event.

Comment: @karllekko your answer was clearer than the answer I linked, therefore the problem was solved. thank you very much.

If you submit your comment as an answer I'll choose it as a best answer.